# JDBC update query updating all columns, when actually I am updating only few columns

Tags: java, database, jpa, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am trying to update only few columns with JDBC.

```
try (Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession(); Connection connection = SessionUtil.getDBConnection(session)){

    connection.setAutoCommit(false);

    String query = "UPDATE Employee SET fname=?, lname=? where id=?";   
    prepareStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);

    for (Employee employee : employeeList) {
        for(int i=1; i<=3; i++){
            if(i==1){
                prepareStatement.setString(i, employee.getFName());
            }
            else if(i==2){
                prepareStatement.setString(i, employee.getLName());
            }
            else if(i==3){
                prepareStatement.setString(i, employee.getID());
            }                                   
        }                           
        prepareStatement.addBatch();
    }
    prepareStatement.executeBatch();                                
    connection.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {         
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here I am trying to update only fname and lname in the table Employee.
But when I check the SQL query generated(from show_sql logs), I can see the update query has all the columns in its set section.

Isn't there a way to limit the no of columns getting updated.
Also since I am updating only 2 columns in the query that I passed to PreparedStatement, shouldn't it do the same instead of trying to update all columns?

Comment: Your `i` will not get value `3` , you need to run your loop  i.e `for(i=1;i<=3;i++)` .

Comment: @Swati sorry a typo. Edited the post. But the issue is still the same

Comment: What do you mean with _"But when I check the SQL query generated(from show_sql logs)"_?

Answer (score 1):

You have three `setString` calls with the same `i`, so you overwrite all the columns with `getID()`. Just drop the inner `for` loop and you should be OK:

```
for (Employee employee : employeeList) {
     prepareStatement.setString(1, employee.getFName());
     prepareStatement.setString(2, employee.getLName());
     prepareStatement.setString(3, employee.getID());
     prepareStatement.addBatch();
}
prepareStatement.executeBatch();
```

Comment: but isn't your code also doing the same thing? I mean I just used a loop to generate the value of i so makes no difference to me. Or am I missing some jdbc concept here ?

Comment: also in my actual code base, I might not know the column count to update at compile time, so using a loop is kinda a must for me

Comment: @DockYard no - the loop in your post sets each column thrice (e.g., it sets 1 with `getFName`, then overwrites 1 with `getLName`, then overwrites it with `getID`, and then the same with 2, etc...

Comment: Oye that was a blunder from me mate. Actually I was facing this issue in my workplace. Due to privacy reason I changed the structure and var names. Made a blunder there, will edit the post. But even still my question is still same. Even with your way, the sql query generated tries to update all columns